# Windows can't detect my Android device

Tags: windows, usb, windows-8.1, android

I am trying to connect my phone*(Android)* to my Laptop using USB cable. The phone is not recognized and it just charges. No notification appear on either my phone or Windows. I tried my best to let Windows detect my phone but useless. Here are things I have done *(before posting)*:

- Googled
- Tested with other cables
- Enabled developer*(USB Debugging)* option in my Phone
- Tried to find any USB option in Settings/Storage *(But useless)*
- Reseted my phone

Nothing rendered to be helpful. All of this has led me to think that something is missing in my Laptop. Like a software.

Why is my Laptop not recognizing my phone? Is there a software required?

<sup><sup>OS:  Windows 8.1

Phone:  Samsung Galaxy Duos 2

Android Version:  4.2.2 (Jelly Bean)

Model Number:  GT-S7582</sup></sup>

[image: my phone img]

Comment: Have you tested in another computer? You should do this most basic troubleshooting before anything else.

Comment: I currently don't have any extra computer.

Comment: As far as I remember Android 4.x doesn't support USB mode switching, it was introduced later. With 4.x it should just work out of the box.

Comment: I think I should get another cable and try with that. Will buy on tomorrow.

Comment: Is there any "USB connect" event, ding-dong, or something? If you use USBTreeView, do you see any new device attached to the tree? Could it be you have a "charge-only" cable?

Comment: @Ale..chenski There is no "USB connect" event or anything like it. I tried using USBTreeView but no new device was attached. I also think its about cables. I will get a new one today.

Comment: Can you see a new device or unknown USB device in device management? You can refer to this article and try these solutions: https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-doesnt-recognize-android/

Comment: @Peter.G I have already tried these solutions :P

Comment: My bad. The problem is with the power port. I even repaired it but didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

**If** the cause would be a software problem, you could try windows update or if you find it possible, doing a "*Fresh restart*" (reinstall) of windows. That should fix any software/driver related issues on your computer.

It might also be that the USB port is *faulty*. Try another USB port that you know works.

(Also, cleaning the usb port and your phones port is a good start)

As mentioned before, you should also try connecting it to another computer.

*To answere your software question:*

*There should not be any special sofware required for your computer to access the phone.*